# show div on when checkboxes are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

So im trying to show a div when one of the multiple checkboxes are clicked and it is working but when you unclick a checkbox it hides the div even when checkboxes are still clicked. I cant seem to figure out how to make it hide the div only when no checkboxes are left clicked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="1" id="fldcheckbox" onclick="fnchecked(this.checked);">

<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="2" id="fldcheckbox" onclick="fnchecked(this.checked);">

<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="3" id="fldcheckbox" onclick="fnchecked(this.checked);">

<div id="ref_options" style="display:none;">
example
</div>

<script>
function fnchecked(blnchecked)
{
if(blnchecked)
{
document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "";
}else{
document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "none";
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: The id `fldcheckbox` is not unique in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are hiding/displaying the div based on the checked value of each checkbox.
When just one checkbox is unchecked then you variable `blnchecked` become false, that makes div invisible.

You probably want this

```
function fnchecked(blnchecked) {
    var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("list[]");
    var ischecked = false;
    for (var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
            ischecked = true;
        }
    }

    if (ischecked) {
        document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "none";
    }
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWL3B/)

You can remove the function parameter as there is no use of it inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` event instead of `click`.

Answer (score 0):

see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2a5nD/)**

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="1" id="fldcheckbox" onclick="fnchecked(this.checked?++c:--c);">
```

java script:

```
<script>
var c=0;
function fnchecked(c){
  if(c>0){
    document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("ref_options").style.display = "none";
  }    
}
</script>
```