# how can click radio then display div or hidden

Tags: javascript, html

when I onclick the radio,

how can display or hidden the div?

because I writing this code, it cannot work.

```
<div class="col-12 gap-24"><div class="row"><span class="col-2"><input class="" type="radio" name="payway" value="5" οnclick="myFunction();">Store</span></div></div>
              </div>

              <script>
              function myFunction() {
                var check_pick = document.getElementById("check_pick");
                var check_pick1 = document.getElementById("check_pick1");
                if (check_pick.style.display === "none") {
                  check_pick.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                  check_pick.style.display = "none";
                }
                if (check_pick1.style.display === "none") {
                  check_pick1.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                  check_pick1.style.display = "none";
                }
              }
              </script>


              <label class="h4" name="check_pick" id="check_pick">Pick up method</label>
              <div class="row_4 border" name="check_pick1" id="check_pick1">
```

Comment: You might want to give https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/ a read-through. You might not even need JS here at all (but if you do: please read up on modern JS a bit: instead of putting `onclick` attributes in your HTML, have a JS file that finds your page elements that need JS logic tied to them using not-even-modern-anymore event listening)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show div on when checkboxes are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068542/show-div-on-when-checkboxes-are-clicked) — "How to (do X) when (Y) is clicked" is one of the _most_ frequently asked questions on Stackoverflow, and though the question I linked is for a checkbox, it is the same for a button or radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set up your listener after window has loaded

```js
window.onload = function() {


/* you can assign a listener like this:

        var radio = document.getElementById('radio');    
        radio.onclick = myFunction;
        
or like this: */

          document.getElementById("radio").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

          var check_pick = document.getElementById("check_pick");
          check_pick.style.display='none'
          
          var check_pick1 = document.getElementById("check_pick1");
          check_pick1.style.display='none'


 }
        


function myFunction() {

  var check_pick = document.getElementById("check_pick");
  
  var radio = document.getElementById("radio");
  
  var check_pick1 = document.getElementById("check_pick1");
  
  
  
  if (check_pick.style.display === "none") {
    check_pick.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    check_pick.style.display = "none";
    radio.checked = false
    
  }
  if (check_pick1.style.display === "none") {
    check_pick1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    check_pick1.style.display = "none";
  } 
}
```

```css
#check_pick,#check_pick1{
display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 gap-24">
  <div class="row">
      <input id='radio' type="radio" name="payway" value="5" />Store
  </div>
</div>




<label class="h4" name="check_pick" id="check_pick">Pick up method</label>
<div class="row_4 border" name="check_pick1" id="check_pick1">xxx</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The really nasty problem with the posted code is the presence of the greek letter **ο**, namely a greek omicron character in lower case, in the attribute value `οnclick="myFunction()`. This stops the onclick attribute being recognized without generating an error:

```js
console.log(
  'οnclick="myFunction();"' === 'onclick="myFunction();"'
);
console.log("0x0" + 'οnclick="myFunction();"'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
```

You may wish to investigate where the omicron came from. Hopefully it was caused by selecting the wrong keyboard language when originally typed in.